# WordPress :: Booking plugin

Tags: cms, calendar, wordpress, plug-in, woocommerce

We have a small website regarding a tennis court.

We have 3 fields and after the login page subscribed users can book one of the 3 fields for 1h.

**PROBLEM:** The problem we are facing is that we cannot organize users to meet one each other. We currently use a WhatsApp chat with more than 200 users and when one offers to meetup at 4pm there are 3-4 users that reply in the WhatsApp chat and it's a mess.

**SOLUTION:** the ideal solution would be to give the chance to users to show that they want to book a field at 4pm. When someone else join that session at 4pm only there the session is booked and both receive the contact information of the other and eventually a message.

I've found [WooCommerce Booking extension](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/) and [WooCommerce Appointments](https://bookingwp.com/plugins/woocommerce-appointments/) but I'm not sure if those can fit.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found a [plugin](https://plugin.ch/) that also has an app for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.plugin.plugin) and [iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/plugin-ch/id592180195?ign-mpt=uo%3D4).